# How to create custom keyboard with my own Gif and other images in Android? Any Tutorial or sample source please?

Tags: android

How to create a custom keyboard with my own Gif and other images in Android? I need to create a custom keyboard which contains Gif images ,I need to develop a keyboard like the below image ,Any Tutorial or sample source available please?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom keyboard by following this tutorial:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

Then in implementing your own images or gif,  create a custom popup window with your images in it by adding a class that extends popup window. See this answer:

[implement popup window on keyboard in android to add images in custom keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110602/implement-popup-window-on-keyboard-in-android-to-add-images-in-custom-keyboard/42429647#42429647)

Add a key with unique keyCode in your keyboard that will trigger and show the popup window.