# How to implement custom Gif keyboard in android?

Tags: android, keyboard, gif

I want to use gif images on the custom keyboard.can anyone please help me how to implement custom Gif keyboard?.

Comment: U need to create a custom class extending the EditText Class for this, refer to my answer below @gowthami

Comment: did it solve? @gowthami

Comment: Were you able to implement this? I have to do same.please help me.

Comment: Does anyone get a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Make a Custom EditText Class like this

```
 public class GifEditText extends EditText {
        public GifEditText(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public GifEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public GifEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        @Override
        public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo editorInfo) {
            final InputConnection ic = super.onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo);
            EditorInfoCompat.setContentMimeTypes(editorInfo,
                    new String[]{"image/gif"});

            final InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener callback =
                    new InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onCommitContent(InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfo,
                                                       int flags, Bundle opts) {
                            // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously
                            if (BuildCompat.isAtLeastNMR1() && (flags &
                                    InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) != 0) {
                                try {
                                    inputContentInfo.requestPermission();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    return false; // return false if failed
                                }
                            }

                            // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously.
                            // call inputContentInfo.releasePermission() as needed.

                            return true;  // return true if succeeded
                        }
                    };
            return InputConnectionCompat.createWrapper(ic, editorInfo, callback);
        }
    }
```

And use like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.test.GifEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Test gif" />
</LinearLayout>
```

For more details you can refer the official documentation :
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom keyboard by following this tutorial:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

Then in implementing your own images or gif, create a custom popup window with your images in it by adding a class that extends popup window. See this answer:

[implement popup window on keyboard in android to add images in custom keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110602/implement-popup-window-on-keyboard-in-android-to-add-images-in-custom-keyboard/42429647#42429647)

Add a key with unique keyCode in your keyboard that will trigger and show the popup window.

Comment: Hi, Rajesh 
Thank you for your reply,
I want a keyboard http://i.stack.imgur.com/ig94m.jpg like this

Answer (score 1):

I got the sample for this by implementing this we can simply create custom gif keyboard

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-CommitContentSampleIME

Comment: I am beginner in Android.if you have any sample application please share.I would like to create same type of application. Thank U very much.